# Pass column values into selection for SQL query using pandas.io.sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have multiple sql queries I need to run (via pandas.io.sql / .read_sql) that have a very similar structure so I am attempting to parameterize them.

I am wondering if there is a way to pass in column values using .format (which works for strings).

My query (truncated to simplify this post):

```
sql= '''
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(report_suite AS STRING) AS report_suite, post_pagename,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(post_visid_high,post_visid_low))) AS unique_visitors 
FROM 
    FOO.db
WHERE 
    date_time BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'
    AND report_suite = '{2}'
GROUP BY 
    report_suite, post_pagename
ORDER BY 
    unique_visitors DESC
'''.format(*parameters)
```

What I would like to do, is be able to parameterize the `COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(post_visid_high, post_visid_low))) as Unique Visitors`

like this somehow:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT({3})) as {'4'}
```

The problem I can't seem to get around is that in order to do this would require storing the column names as something other than a string to avoid the quotes. Is there any good ways around this?

Comment: For starters: please **do not** pass values to SQL queries using string formatting. It is a bad habit that is both insecure and overly complicated (quoting etc.). Use suitable placeholders and pass your params to [`read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) *separately* using the `params` keyword argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you have any recommendations on where I can find documentation on this method?

Comment: Second, if you need dynamic SQL, you might as well learn to use [SQLAlchemy Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html), which is well suited for query building.

Comment: Regarding placeholders, params, and documentation: start by reading pandas' docs on `read_sql()`, especially `params` kwarg. From there move on to reading your DB-API driver's docs on the matter. And do read the SQLA Core docs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
sql_dynamic_parms = dict(
  func1='CONCAT(post_visid_high,post_visid_low)',
  name1='unique_visitors'
)

sql= '''
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(report_suite AS STRING) AS report_suite, post_pagename,
    COUNT(DISTINCT({func1})) AS {name1} 
FROM 
    FOO.db
WHERE 
    date_time BETWEEN %(date_from)s AND %(date_to)s
    AND report_suite = %(report_suite)s
GROUP BY 
    report_suite, post_pagename
ORDER BY 
    unique_visitors DESC
'''.format(**sql_dynamic_parms)

params = dict(
  date_from=pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01'),
  date_to=pd.to_datetime('2017-12-01'),
  report_suite=111
)

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=params)
```

PS you may want to read [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) to see what kind of parameter placeholders are accepted

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking to do.

Comment: @Jasonc200, glad I could help :)

Comment: @IljaEverilä, do you mean that using `:name` instead of `%(name)s` is a preferred way? ([PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/))

Comment: Nah, I mean remove the left over quotes from around it. They'll cause trouble, for example a resulting query might look like `''2017-01-01''`, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, duh! Thank you! :-)